# how to create Delphi 4 structure to map column names in XLS to column names in SQL

Tags: sql, delphi

I have an EXCEL sheet.it has various form-fields that are named as

```
 “smrBgm133GallonsGross/ smrBgm167GallonsGross “
```

and

```
 “smrEgm133GallonsGross/ smrEgm167GallonsGross “
```

I added to the XCEL sheets 2 new form fields named
                    `smrBgm167GrosGalnsDA/smrEgm167GrosGalnsDA`

The above additons I made in EXCEL should ACTUALLy be named as

```
`smrBgm229GallonsGross/smrEgm229GallonsGross` because. This is a  MUST  for the Delphi application to function properly.
```

This Delphi-4 application extracts , and vewrifys the form DATA in tandem with the DB.

My Delphi-4 application works (checks/inserts/retrieves)  so that current  months beginning gallon of milk “bgm229”  is equal to last months ending  gallon of milk “egm229”  , and then throw an exception if they are different.

Excel sheets:-  Bgm167GrosGalnsDA/  Egm160GrosGalnsDA
Delphi Code (DB- input/ DB- output/validation):-     bgm229/ egm229
SQL 2005 DB:- bgm167DA/ egm167DA
Actually the columns I ADDED should have been **named asa "smrEgm133GallonsGross/ smrEgm167GallonsGross "...I** messed up in naming them and they are on the production now....

In the Delphi procedure,for  the beginning  inventory, the code  it is

```
  ExtractFormBgmInfo(smrMilkAvMilk,  'smrBgm133');
  ExtractFormBgmInfo(smrMilkDe,           'smrBgm167');
```

For ending   inventory  the  code  it is

```
  ExtractFormEgmInfo(smrMilkAvMilk,  'smrEgm133');
  ExtractFormEgmInfo(smrMilkDe,           'smrEgm167');
```

I am adding “smrBgm229GrosGalns/smrEgm229GrosGalns” to the list 
But the issue is that they are named erroneously as “smrBgm167GrosGalnsDA/ smrEgm167GrosGalnsDA” IN THE EXCEL sheets, while they are to be named as 'smrBgm229/'smrEgm229''(as is the case in the Delphi code). Hence. I added ...to the above

```
  ExtractFormBgmInfo(smrMilkAvMilk,    'smrBgm133');
  ExtractFormBgmInfo(smrMilkDe,           'smrBgm167');
  ExtractFormBgmInfo(smrMilkDyedDe,       'smrBgm229'); 

  ExtractFormEgmInfo(smrMilkAvMilk,      'smrEgm133');
  ExtractFormEgmInfo(smrMilkDe,           'smrEgm167');
  ExtractFormEgmInfo(smrMilkDyedDe,       'smrEgm229');
```

**This throws an error  , as smrBgm229GallonsGross /smrEgm229GallonsGross  are not defined in the EXCEL sheets** .So the issue is **how do I convert “smrBgm167GrosGalnsDA” from Excel sheets into “smrBgm229GallonsGross”** and then make my “ExtractForm” statement correct?

Please help there is an release scheduled today and got to discuss this with my superirors

Comment: You have a separate column for every possible price of a gallon of milk? I think you're doing it wrong. And why do you want to put the data for $2.29 into the column for $1.61?

Comment: Actually all columns should have been **named asa "bgm229/ egm229"...I** messed up in naming them and they are on the production now....So basic Idea is I want to do is

 

`IF the excel value is Bgm167 GrosGalns DA 
     then cosider it as  bgm229/ egm229`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is *map* one string to another. You can use a simple string list for that.

```
// Declare the variable somewhere, such as at unit scope or as a field
// of your form class
var
  ColumnNameMap: TStrings;
```

---

```
// Somewhere else, such as unit initialization or a class constructor,
// initialize the data structure with the column-name mappings.    
ColumnNameMap := TStringList.Create;
ColumnNameMap.Values['Bgm167 GrosGalns DA'] := 'bgm229/ egm229';
```

---

```
// In yet a third place in your code, use something like this to map
// the column name in your input to the real column name in your output.
i := ColumnNameMap.IndexOfName(ColumnName);
if i >= 0 then
  RealColumnName := ColumnNameMap.Values[ColumnName]
else
  RealColumnName := ColumnName;
```

Later versions of Delphi have the generic [`TDictionary`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Generics.Collections.TDictionary) class. Use `TDictionary<string, string>`. The [`TStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings) solution I outlined above will have problems if any of the column names can have equals signs in them, but you can mitigate that by changing the [`NameValueSeparator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings.NameValueSeparator) property.

```
var
  ColumnNameMap: TDictionary<string, string>;
```

---

```
ColumnNameMap := TDictionary<string, string>.Create;
ColumnNameMap.Add('Bgm167 GrosGalns DA', 'bgm229/ egm229');
```

---

```
if not ColumnNameMap.TryGetValue(ColumnName, RealColumnName) then
  RealColumnName := ColumnName;
```

Comment: Rob, i have updated the Probelm definition  and still working on your solution .

Comment: I am gettging identifier redeclared for both the variables

ColumnNameMap := TStringList.Create;

 ColumnNameMap.Values['Bgm167 GrosGalns DA'] := 'bgm229/ egm229';

Comment: i am getting error // "incompatible type "class" and "string" reference"// for the "ColumnNameMap  := TStrings;".

Should i define "  ColumnNameMap" as a ssting in the "var"?

Comment: I defined  ColumnNameMap as   " ColumnNameMap: TStringList; " ...
gettinbg two errors

Comment: [Error] BgmExcel.pas(2263): Incompatible types: 'TStringList' and 'Class reference' [Error] BgmExcel.pas

Comment: I'm sorry. I assumed you understood Delphi syntax, such as where variable declarations are allowed and when it is appropriate to declare variables them versus use them. I'll edit to be more clear. If you still have trouble with syntax, please ask a separate question since it has nothing to do with data structures or converting one string to another.

Comment: (2266): Undeclared identifier: ' 'Bgm167GrosGalns DA''

Comment: thyanks Rob I am just a few inches away from a solution
sorry to bombard you  with the step by step ...solution/errors i gave....

Comment: But I got one Question ....THE issue I WAS GETTING is in ONE Procedure (delphi)....should I add the above CORRECTION AS A SEPERATE Procedure /FUNCTION or in the same Procedure (delphi), as the main issue is?

Comment: Declare the variable in a single place that makes it accessible to all the places that need to use the variable. Initialize the variable and fill the list exactly once. Use it wherever you need. Maybe that's all in a single procedure, or maybe it's throughout your entire program. I don't know because I can't see your code.