# missing "htmlview.dcu"

Tags: delphi

While compling Delphi application there is an error

```
"file not found "htmlview.dcu".
```

The errror is not on my system ,but someone else's.

I checked it my system and its there in  " C:\Program Files\PBear\Thtml\package".

Whats the remedy if there is an error

```
 "file not found "htmlview.dcu".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, if it tells you it can't find a DCU file, what it *really* means is that it can't find the unit at all, i.e. neither the source nor the DCU.  Make sure the other person has htmlview.pas, and that they have it either included  in the DPR or in a folder that's either on the Library Path for their Delphi installation or the Search Path for the project that needs it.

Comment: Thanks Mason , I did send them the file and Link.

Comment: @Mason: I have to disagree (but only slightly). <g> If the compiler tells you the **.dcu** can't be found, the .dcu is missing. If you have the .dcu and it tells you the **.pas** can't be found, the .dcu was compiled with a different Delphi version.

Comment: @Ken:  Yes, but if you have no DCU available but you do have the .pas file, it won't give you this message, it'll recompile the DCU from the .pas.  That's what I meant by this.  You have to be missing both to get the "DCU not found" message.

Answer (score 0):

If you found the error on someone else's system, but not yours, and found the missing .DCU on your own system, you need to give them the .DCU from your system.

If you think about the error message before posting here, it would be pretty clear I'd think. "File not found " very clearly tells you it can't find the file , so you need to give it to them. Doesn't it?

Comment: I did copy/attach them the file, but it seems it did not work out out.

Comment: Then give them the .pas file that the .dcu came from. Better yet, give them the link to THTMLView and have them download and install the entire component set; that way they'll have all the files they need. BTW, if giving them the .DCU alone didn't work, it means that they're using a different version of Delphi than you, and **that** means they automatically need the source - .DCUs are not compatible across versions of Delphi (except for D2006-D2007 only).

Comment: Thanks   Ken  ! I have a major issue. Can you look at this please ,its very simple for you but seems like a tough nut to me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460297/how-to-create-delphi-4-structure-to-map-column-names-in-xls-to-column-names-in-sq
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463181/undeclared-identifier

Comment: I have looked at both of them. Rob Kennedy gave you a very complete answer to both of those questions; I'm not sure what else you'd want me to tell you.